# Validate Checkbox Checked Jquery with multiple checked or unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i need help, anybody help me for checkbox using javascript?
this is my script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery With Example</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            var chkId = '';
            $('.chkNumber:checked').each(function () {
                chkId += $(this).val() + ",";
            });
            chkId = chkId.slice(0, -1);


            $('.chkSelectAll').click(function () {
                $('.chkNumber').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="chkSelectAll" />SelectAll
            </td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkNumber" value="1" />One</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkNumber" value="2" />Two</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkNumber" value="3" />Three</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkNumber" value="4" />Four</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkNumber" value="5" />Five<br /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

i want if i checked/unchecked all value 1-5 class(chkSelectAll) is checked/unchecked.

give me solution please...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w8z9y/ this code works like a charm, what is the problem then? Are you sure this works:  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")???

Comment: i'm using sample with mvc so i render jquery script, i mean if i checked value 1-3, checkbox class(chkSelectAll) still false checked, and if i continue checked checkbox 4-5 that mean value 1-5(all checked), checkbox class(chkSelectAll) is selected checked true. im confuse...please help,

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood your question, you need to check if the checkboxes changed and check if all changed.

```
$('.chkNumber').change(function() { 
    $('.chkSelectAll').prop('checked',$('.chkNumber:checked').length == $('.chkNumber').length);
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8z9y/1/

Comment: i also misunedrstand OP question but you have posted right.